# Is it possible to extend arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm used to add methods to external classes like IEnumerable. But can we extend Arrays in C#?

I am planning to add a method to arrays that converts it to a IEnumerable even if it is multidimensional.

Not related to [How to extend arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628427/how-to-extend-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
static class Extension
{
    public static string Extend(this Array array)
    {
        return "Yes, you can";
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,,,] multiDimArray = new int[10,10,10,10];
        Console.WriteLine(multiDimArray.Extend());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "this Array array" mean in the method. I think Array is an abstract class so what are you exactly doing here by writing "this Array array"?

Comment: this Array array means that *this Array* is referring to the type that is to be extended.
*this Array* could just as well be *this T*, where the method would be
*public static void Extend<T>(this T obj)*. The identifier merely gives the type a name, so it can be referenced in the extending method.

Comment: @VatsalSura: "this Array array" refers to "extend any kind of array", as opposed to a more specific array kind, e.g. object[], object[][] or object[,] (or another type, as well as generics, instead of the example type "object"). I think this is what you were querying about.

Answer (score 41):

Yes. Either through extending the `Array` class as already shown, or by extending a specific kind of array or even a generic array:

```
public static void Extension(this string[] array)
{
  // Do stuff
}

// or:

public static void Extension<T>(this T[] array)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

The last one is not exactly equivalent to extending `Array`, as it wouldn't work for a multi-dimensional array, so it's a little more constrained, which could be useful, I suppose.

Comment: +1 Your implementation is more type-safe than @maciejkow's. I wrote some array extension methods using a similar method some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I did it!

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this Array target)
    {
        foreach (var item in target)
            yield return (T)item;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "this Array target" mean in the method. I think Array is an abstract class so what are you exactly doing here by writing "this Array target"?