# How to inherit from Arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, inheritance

I need an array with custom methods.

```
MyObject[] myObject = {myA, myB, myC};
myObject.myMethod(); // do my stuff
```

*1. Is that possible?*

*2. How would `myMethod` be able to internally access `myA`, `myB`, and `myC`?*

-

PS: Sorry to deceive all the *down voting c# wizards*, here. But I'm just starting with the language and I don't know about "Enumerations" of the [referred question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183083/is-it-possible-to-extend-arrays-in-c) . So I did made a simpler straighter question with the hope of helping the ones of my kind.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Creating a class that contains the array and methods to manipulate the data may be a better way forwards.

Comment: I'd rather *not* extend arrays, but `IEnumerable<MyObject>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q:** Is that possible?

**A:** Yes, but you cannot inherit from Array. A different mechanism will help you, though.

**Q:** How would myMethod be able to internally access myA, myB, and myC?

**A:** You can use Extension Methods approach, as shown below:

```
static class Extension
{
    public static string Extend(this Array array)
    {
        return "Yes, you can";
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,,,] multiDimArray = new int[10,10,10,10];
        Console.WriteLine(multiDimArray.Extend());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write Extension methods, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx)

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static class MyExtensions
        {
            public static void myMethod(this MyObject[] items)
            {
                foreach(var item in items)
                {
                   //do something;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```